# Global pointers between functions

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

So I was trying to use a global pointer that I define in a function and I'm going to use in another function without passing as parameters.

Here is my fun.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *step;
int step_counter;

int init(int num){
    step = &num;
    step_counter = *step;
    return 0;

}
void reset_counter(){
    step_counter = *step;
    printf("%d ", step_counter);

}
```

Here is the main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fun.c"

int main()
{
    init(3);
    reset_counter();
return 0;
}
```

I was expecting that the reset_counter function to print 3. But instead it prints out 0. I don't know what's the problem. I'm pretty new to C.

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behavior.

You point `step` to the address of `num` but `num` is a local variable that's destroyed after `init()` returns. Trying to derefence `step` in `reset_counter()` gives you UB as what it's pointing to is already destroyed.

Why are you using a pointer for `step`? You could just use `step = num;` and have `step` be an `int`.

Comment: I tought that i don't have to define unnecessary integer (since it takes up memory), if it was already defined before (in the parameters). Now that i know that parameter just get destroyed instead of saved in memory. Thanks for your answer and the advice.

Answer (score 1):

In this function

```
int init(int num){
    step = &num;
    step_counter = *step;
    return 0;

}
```

parameter `num` is a local variable of the function. After exiting the function the variable will not be alive and its memory can be reused by some other parts of the program.

As result the pointer `step` will have an invalid value and the program will have undefined behavior if it'll try to access the memory pointed to by the pointer.

You could rewrite the function the following way.

```
int init(int num){
    step = malloc( sizeof( *step );

    int success step != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        *step = num;
        step_counter = *step;
    }

    return success;
}
```

You should not forget to free the pointer before exiting the program.

Though it is not clear why you need the additional variable `step_counter`.

I would rewrite the code snippet the following way

```
int *step;

int init(int num){
    step = malloc( sizeof( *step ) );

    int success = step != NULL;

    if ( success ) *step = num;

    return success;
}

void reset_step(){
    free( step );
    step = NULL;
}
```